# "How to get test run id from a specific release using TFS 2018 API"

Tags: selenium, tfs, release-management

We have a task in our release pipeline that runs Seleniumtests(Visual studio test task). The selenium tests run and we can after the run add an attachment to the testrun manually. We also manage to add an attachment with the api but we don't have a good way to extract the testrunid that is necessary for the upload.

How do we in a good way get the test run id from a release so we can bind the attachment to the right testrun. We only manage to get all test runs with the api, which is alot.

[Where we want the attachment to be uploaded with the api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMm0y.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question to clarify the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see test run id from the test log for a specific release.

So, the simplest way is getting the specific test run id with the REST API from the log.

```
GET https://{instance}/{project}/_apis/release/releases/{releaseId}/environments/{environmentId}/deployPhases/{releaseDeployPhaseId}/tasks/{taskId}/logs?api-version={version}
```

See [Get task log](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/rm/releases#get-task-log) for details.

**EDIT** [Get Task Log v5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/get%20task%20log?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0)

Comment: @andy-li-msft would you be able to help me out here, please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53396168/how-to-get-test-run-result-id-from-a-specific-release-using-tfs-2018-api

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following API to get test results for the release,
`GET https://{instance}/{project}/_apis/ResultDetailsByRelease?releaseId={RELEASE.RELEASEID}&releaseEnvId={RELEASE.ENVIRONMENTURID}`

The test results included testRun ID or get failed tests only by using filter,
`GET https://{instance}/{project}/_apis/ResultDetailsByRelease?releaseId={RELEASE.RELEASEID}&releaseEnvId=RELEASE.ENVIRONMENTURID}&%24filter=Outcome+eq+Failed`