# How to get test run result id from a specific release using TFS 2018 API

Tags: selenium, tfs, automated-tests, azure-devops

This question is very similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47415429/how-to-get-test-run-id-from-a-specific-release-using-tfs-2018-api) however I am trying to identify the specific id of the test **result** during the execution of the test. This is so that I can mark the screen shot with the specific id and attach it to the **test run result** after the execution. (This is, in turn, because the REST API does not return any results until the execution is complete.)

I am looking for a way to get the id's of the individually highlighted items during their execution:

[image]

Currently, I retrieve id's such as the release id during its execution like this:

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("RELEASE_RELEASEID")
```

But I do not know how to get information about the tests at that time.